# Unity tilemap collider not colliding with rigidbody

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap, rigidbody, collider

[image]
In the wireframe you can see the tilemap collider for this hill. The red circle falls right through however. The circle has a 2D rigidbody attached. Everything is on the Default sorting layer and on layer order 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to put a circle collider on the red circle. Leaving this up for others who might run into the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Glad to hear you resolved your problem. Don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/228147) - we do that instead of things like putting 'solved' in question titles - it's a bit cleaner & works better with the search options. Good luck with your game.

Comment: Will do. Since it's my own answer, it appears I have to wait 2 days to check the resolved checkmark.  I thought I should somehow mark it solved until then. Is that incorrect to do?

Comment: Yes, there is a two day wait for accepting your own answer & yes, on Stack Exchange [don't add 'solved'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/228147) to titles. That being said, I also erred - I should have rolled back your edit & added a comment on why rather than undoing it with my own. Goes to show we're all still learning.